# How you running more than one instance of parse on multi core servers?

Tags: heroku, parse-server, pm2

I'm wondering if anyone is running something like pm2, forever or what ever to run more than one parse instance on servers that more than a few cores?

If so can you provide any suggestions on something simple, we might be using Heroku and some of their bigger servers can have up to 8 cores and if your not taking advantage of all 8 its a waste of money.

Comment: Kinda silly to negative vote this, its a legit question unless these are down votes from companies competing against the open source parse.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure PM2 using exec_mode=cluster and instance=40.
I'm running 40 instance parse-server in 6 core vps.

*edited*:

I'm changed my configuration using instances=-1, it means you are using available core -1. Or you can use all available core with instances=0.

These are my ecosystem.json setup :

`{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "parse-production",
    "script"      : "/usr/bin/parse-server",
    "watch"       : false, //true,
    "instances"   : -1,
    "exec_mode"   : "cluster",
    "max_memory_restart" : "150M",
    "merge_logs"  : true,
    "cwd"         : "/root",
...`

My server have 6 core, so PM2 create 5 instances of parse server

Comment: could you provide some more details on the setup, im currently running running parse server on Heroku, and their high performance ones have many many cores to take advantage of.